# 同じ番号を持つグループの中でステータスが混在している場合だけ値を更新するSQL文を作成したい

Tags: sql

1個のテーブル(A_TBL)の中で、「A番号」、「B番号」、「C番号」が共に同じレコードが存在することがあり、それらの中で「ステータス1」が”0”と”1”が混在している場合があります。

その条件に合致する全てのレコードに対して、「ステータス1」を”2"、「ステータス2」を”0”にするSQL文を作りたいのですが、上手くいきません。

どなたかご教示をお願いできますでしょうか。

(例）「A_TBL」
項目名：   　A番号  ,  B番号,    C番号 ,   ステータス1 ,   ステータス2

---

```
      "A001"  "B001"   "C01"        0            1
      "A001"  "B001"   "C01"        0            1
      "A001"  "B001"   "C01"        0            1
```

---

```
      "A002"  "B001"   "C01"        1            1
      "A002"  "B001"   "C01"        1            1
```

---

```
      "A003"  "B002"   "C01"        1            1
      "A003"  "B002"   "C01"        1            1
      "A003"  "B002"   "C01"        0            1
```

---

```
      "A004"  "B002"   "C02"        1            1
      "A004"  "B002"   "C02"        1            1
      "A004"  "B002"   "C02"        1            1
```

---

```
      "A005"  "B002"   "C01"        1            1
      "A005"  "B002"   "C01"        0            1
      "A005"  "B002"   "C01"        1            1
```

---

（（例）の表記に誤りがあり、修正しました。sayuri様、指摘ありがとうございました。）

上記の内、「A003/B002/C01」と「A005/B002/C01」の組合せグループが変更対象となります。
この3レコードに対して、ステータス1を"2"に、ステータス2を"0"に変更したいのですが。。

RDBMSは「SQL Server 2016」です。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「A005/B002/C01」は対象に含まれないのでしょうか？ 何か別の条件がありますか？

Comment: あ。。C番号が違うなら、線で区別して、また違うグループである表記にしないといけないですね。。
（例）の書き方が間違っていました。指摘ありがとうございます。修正しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「A003/B002/C01」と「A005/B002/C01」の組合せグループが対象であれば、「A番号」、「B番号」、「C番号」が**同一**かつ「ステータス1」が**異なる**レコードが存在するものをUPDATEすることで[対応可能](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fe218/1)です。(SQL Server 2017で確認)

```
update T
set    STATUS1 = 2,
       STATUS2 = 0
from   A_TBL T,
       A_TBL D
where  T.A_ID = D.A_ID
and    T.B_ID = D.B_ID
and    T.C_ID = D.C_ID
and    T.STATUS1 <> D.STATUS1;
```

Comment: payaneco様、ご教示ありがとうございます。

試してみました。出来ました！
havingやgroup by 等を使った長文で、色々と試していた自分が恥ずかしいです。
ありがとうございました！


別質問にするべきかどうか迷ったのですが。。

大変申し訳ありませんが、もう1点だけ、お教えいただきく。


これをVIEWで行うことは、出来ないでしょうか？

前回の質問の条件では、「1つのテーブル」で、と書かせていただきましたが、
これをVIEWにするかもしれないという話も出てきました。

VIEWを作って試してみたところ、
「変更が複数のベース テーブルに影響するので、ビューまたは関数 'T' は更新可能ではありません。」
というエラーとなります。

VIEWでは、このような検索は出来ないのでしょうか？

因みに、
「A番号」、「B番号」、「C番号」、「ステータス1」は、『A_TBL』
「ステータス2」は、『B_TBL』
になります。

追加で質問するなんてすみません。。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @greenmie 別質問にすべきです。

Comment: @htb さんのコメントに同意します。コメントでは「A_TBL、B_TBLはテーブルなのかVIEWなのか」「VIEWのカラムは何か」「VIEWを直接UPDATEしたいのか、VIEWを通じて取得したテーブルのレコードを更新したいのか」などの条件を明示するのが難しいと思います。なので新しい質問を作成し、TABLEとVIEWのカラムやデータ、作成したSQLとエラーメッセージを列挙した[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)をご提示いただくと、より良い回答が集まりやすくなると期待できます。

Comment: そうですよね。また改めて別質問としてアップしようと思います。htb様、payaneco様、ありがとうございました。